# "Unable to retrieve analytics data. Please try again."

Tags: drupal-8, apigee

I am using APIGEE Kickstart drupal distribution. On hitting the analytics tab in apps created, I am getting "Unable to retrieve analytics data. Please try again." and export csv file option is not coming.

Can anyone has the solution for this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDiTc.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the error log that will give you the root cause of the issue I was having the same issue and realised that the environment to query for analytics was not enabled you can check this under Configuration >> Apigee Edge >> Apps >> General app settings